# rewrite mod giving internal server error when trying to rewrite links

Tags: php, .htaccess, html

There is many questions discussing rewrite mod problems i have read them and none solved my unique problem, i already done 3 hour of research to solve it and still stuck.

i want to rewrite links in a source code retrieved  from remote site through file get contents php function,

when i get the source code the link structure is

```
<a href='javascript:openWindow("index1.php?option=com_lsh&view=lsh&event_id=148730&tv_id=850&tid=34143&channel=0&tmpl=component&layout=popup&Itemid=335","735","770")'  >Link#1</a>
```

i want to rewrite to

```
<a href='javascript:openWindow("http://remotesite.com/index1.php?option=com_lsh&view=lsh&event_id=148730&tv_id=850&tid=34143&channel=0&tmpl=component&layout=popup&Itemid=335","735","770")'  >Link#1</a>
```

after research i thought that rewite mod will do the trick and tried the put the code below in my htaccess file

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index1\.php?option - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule  http://remotesite/index1.php?option [L]
```

but it give me internal server error 
what i am doing wrong here?
is there is any other way to rewrite the link structure the way described above?

Answer (score 1):

You can't rewrite DOM objects, apache's mod_rewrite rewrites requests, not DOM. The correct place for you to achieve whatever you're trying to do is at your php script which get file content.

Comment: Mr Marcel thank you for pointing me but do you hvae any ideas how to acheive this in my php code

Comment: You should place a question at StackOverflow about this.